# Authorised invoices pending approval in Xero api

Tags: php, xero-api

I have an app that has been working since 2018 in the last few months all invoices sent to Xero as DRAFT and then set to AUTHORISED are saying pending approval in XERO. This is causing my client some issues in having to manually confirm them (effectively doing this twice, in the app and then in Xero) What could be causing this? the app is linking to Xero and saying it is AUTHORISED and the processing is successful.

A bit more on how we are doing this. When the invoices are created they are created within the app only as DRAFT. The admin in the app can then overview the invoices and set them as AUTHORISED. When this happens the invoice is sent to Xero as a DRAFT invoice, line items are then added and we then set it as AUTHORISED.

The function to do this (using php) is authoriseInvoice which is this:

```
    public function authoriseInvoice( &$output, $sendEmail = true ): void
    {
        $user = null;
        $xdoc = Setting::find_by_name( 'xero_draft_on_create' );
        $xap  = Setting::find_by_name( 'xero_attach_pdf' );
        $xaf  = Setting::find_by_name( 'xero_attach_file' );
        try {
            $company = Company::find($this->company_id);
        } catch (RecordNotFound $e) {
            $company = null;
        }
        if ( $this->type === 1 ) {
            $user = Client::find_by_user_id( $this->user_id );
        } elseif ( $this->type === 2 ) {
            try {
                $user = User::find($this->user_id);
            } catch (RecordNotFound $e) {
                $user = null;
            }
        }
        $xero              = new VivattiXero();
        $result            = array();
        $result['success'] = true;
        $xeroTenantId      = null;
        $apiResponse       = null;
        $accountingApi     = null;
        $flag              = false;

        // submit to Xero
        if ( !is_null ( $company->oauth2 ) ) {
            // update to Xero
            if ( is_null( $this->invoice_id ) ) {
                // So first lets see if we can find this user in xero if not we will add it
                try {
                    $result = $xero->retrieveContact($user, $company);

                    if ( $result['success'] === true && isset( $result['contact_id'] ) ) {
                        $contact_id = $result['contact_id'];
                    } else {
                        $contact_id = null;
                    }
                    if ( is_null( $contact_id ) ) {
                        // error adding contact
                        $result['success'] = false;
                        $result['message'] = 'No Contact ID was returned from the contractId retrieve process.';
                    } elseif ( $xdoc->value === '0' ) {
                        // invoice will not have an id so we create a new invoice with a status of Auth
                        $result = $xero->draftInvoice( $this, $contact_id );
                    }
                } catch (IdentityProviderException | RecordNotFound $e) {
                    $result['success'] = false;
                    $result['message'] = $e->getMessage();
                }

            } else {
                try {
                    [$xeroTenantId, $accountingApi, $identityApi] = VivattiXero::getApiConnection($company);
                    unset( $identityApi );
                    $guid = $this->invoice_id;
                    $apiResponse = $accountingApi->getInvoice( $xeroTenantId, $guid );
                    $result = array(
                        'success'       => true,
                        'xeroTenantId'  => $xeroTenantId,
                        'apiResponse'   => $apiResponse,
                        'accountingApi' => $accountingApi
                    );
                } catch (IdentityProviderException $e) {
                    $result['success'] = false;
                    $result['message'] = $e->getMessage();
                }

            }
        } else {
            $result = array();
            $result['success'] = true;
        }
        // Set is auth as -1 which is authorised but not paid
        if ( $result['success'] ) {
            $this->paid = -1;
            if ( $this->save() ) {
                $records = array(
                    'invoice' => $this,
                    'user' => $user
                );

                if ( $this->type === 1 ) {
                    $hours = ProjectTimeItem::find_all_by_is_invoiced( $this->id );
                    $costs = ProjectExpenseItem::find_all_by_is_invoiced( $this->id );
                } else {
                    $hours = ProjectTimeItem::find_all_by_contractor_invoiced( $this->id );
                    $costs = ProjectExpenseItem::find_all_by_contractor_invoiced( $this->id );
                }
                foreach ( $hours as $pti ) {
                    //if ( time2hours( $pti->time ) == 0 ) $flag = true;
                    if ( $this->type === 1 ) {
                        $project               = Project::find($pti->project_id);
                        $client                = Client::find($project->client_id);
                        $pti->client_primary   = $client->hourly_rate;
                        $pti->client_secondary = $client->reduced_rate;
                    }
                    $pti->is_locked = 1;
                    $pti->save();
                }
                if ( $flag === false ) {
                    foreach ( $costs as $pei ) {
                        $pei->is_locked = 1;
                        $pei->save();
                    }

                    if ( $result['success'] === true ) {
                        $result['success'] = $this->snapshotInvoice();
                        if ( $result['success'] !== true ) {
                            $this->undoSnapshotInvoice();
                            $this->paid = 0;
                            $this->save();
                            $result['message'] = 'Could not snapshot Time items, Invoice has not been authorised. Please try again.';
                        }
                    }

                    if ( $result['success'] === true ) {
                        // submit to Xero
                        if ( !is_null( $company->oauth2 ) && $this->hourly_rate > 0.0 ) {
                            // update to Xero
                            $result = $xero->authoriseInvoice( $this, $result );

                            if ( $result['success'] && $xap->value === '1' ) {
                                try {
                                    $result = $xero->attachPDF($this);
                                } catch (RecordNotFound | IdentityProviderException $e) {
                                    $result['success'] = true;
                                    $result['message'] = ' Invoice was successful but the PDF has not been sent to Xero';
                                }
                            } elseif ( $result['success'] && $xaf->value === '1' ) {
                                try {
                                    $result = $xero->attachPNG($this);
                                } catch (RecordNotFound | IdentityProviderException $e) {
                                    $result['success'] = true;
                                    $result['message'] = ' Invoice was successful but the PNG has not been sent to Xero';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if ( $result['success'] ) {
                            if ( $sendEmail === true ) {
                                $attach = Setting::find_by_name( 'email_pdf_attach' )->value;
                                $subject = 'Invoice number #' . sprintf( '%08d', $this->id );
                                if ( $attach === '1' ) {
                                    $template = 'invoice/email/attach-pdf';
                                } else {
                                    $template = 'invoice/email/default';
                                }
                                try {
                                    [$message, $status] = emailUser($records, $subject, $template);
                                } catch (RecordNotFound | MissingRequiredMIMEParameters $e) {
                                    $status = false;
                                    $message = 'The email failed to send';
                                }
                                //$output['html'] = noticeMessage( '<b>Email Response</b> ' . $message );
                                $output['success'] = $status;
                                $output['message'] = $message . '. The Invoice ';
                            } else {
                                $output['message'] = 'Invoice number #' . sprintf( '%08d', $this->id ) . ' has been successfully authorised';
                                $output['success'] = true;
                            }
                            $output['reload'] = true;
                        } else {
                            $this->paid = 0;
                            $this->save();
                            $this->undoSnapshotInvoice();
                            $output['success'] = false;
                            $output['message'] = $result['message'];
                        }
                    } else {
                        $this->paid = 0;
                        $this->save();
                        $this->undoSnapshotInvoice();
                        $output['success'] = false;
                        $output['message'] = $result['message'];
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->paid = 0;
                    $this->save();
                    $this->undoSnapshotInvoice();
                    $output['success'] = false;
                    $output['message'] = 'Could not authorise Invoice. It contains Zero time entries. Please disable the time item.';
                }
            } else {
                $this->paid = 0;
                $this->save();
                $this->undoSnapshotInvoice();
                $output['success'] = false;
                $output['message'] = 'Could not authorise Invoice. Please try again.';
            }
        } else {
            $this->undoSnapshotInvoice();
            $output['success'] = false;
            $output['message'] = $result['message'];
        }
    }
```